# Determing layout at runtime in listView

Tags: android

```
public AdapterClass(Context a, int resourceID, List < Info > entries) {
    super(a, resourceID, entries);
    this.layoutResource = resourceID;
}

@
Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Object custom = getItem(position);
    LinearLayout rowView = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        rowView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi.inflate(layoutResource, rowView);
    } else
        rowView = (LinearLayout) convertView;

    if (custom != null) {

    }
    return rowView;
}
```

I am passing two different layouts at runtime, how can i identify which layout i am passing in the `getView()` method. I am using `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: @PankajKumar: which code you would require, do u want to the way i am passing it to the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the layout ID's to check which layout is passed

```
if(passedresourceID == R.layout.layout1)
{
    //do something
}
else if(passedresourceID == R.layout.layout2)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks sankar... passedResouceID is an int and R.layout.layout1... will it work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check against the parent id that was passed to `getView()`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

switch (parent.getId()){   //check your ids here
case (R.layout.layoutToCheck):
break;
case (R.layout.otherLayoutToCheck):
...

final Object custom = getItem(position);
LinearLayout rowView = null;
if (convertView == null) {
    rowView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vi.inflate(layoutResource, rowView);
```

Comment: Thanks, i am not getting R.id.layoutToCheck though i have an id for it in R.Java

Comment: `R.id.YourLayoutName` returns the `id` that is contained in `R.java`